# PPA GPG key from bash script

Tags: apt, bash, ppa, keyrings

Let's suppose that I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 and that I want to add my preferred PPAs from Launchpad.

I know that I can use the `add-apt-repository`, but it does not currently add the PPA keys in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` (or, generally speaking, in a proper directory set by the user, like `/usr/local/share/keyrings/` may be). Put the key in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` will be the future standard, and it is already supported by Ubuntu 21.10.

Therefore, I would like to write a bash script that, parsing the *.list files that the user had already copied from a backup to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, gets the keys and copy them, for instance, to `/usr/local/share/keyrings/`

Which is a clever way to get the key file, if I know the PPA name in the form `ppa:${PPA_NAME}/${PKG_NAME}`?

My first idea is:

- Knowing `${PPA_NAME}` and `${PKG_NAME}` go to the correct launchpad.net web page
- Parse the web page to get the fingerprint
- Use the fingerprint to download the key file from https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/
- Generate a key in the correct format and put it in the correct path (referred by the `signed-by` option in *.list files)

Another way may be run a silent `apt update`, catch a possible NO_PUBKEY Error and use it for retrieving the keyfile.

Are there less convoluted ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question was posted by myself in 2021, but recently I have written a bash script that, having as input the name of a launchap ppa in the format `ppa:[ppa_user]/[ppa_name]`, creates the `.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and put the related keyring in a configurable folder.

The script is split in two files, a `add-launchpad-ppa.conf` and a `add-launchpad-ppa.sh` file.

`add-launchpad-ppa.conf` file content:

```bash
# Set English language
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# Color settings
COLOR_ERROR="\e[1;31m"
COLOR_OFF="\e[0m"
COLOR_OK="\e[1;32m"
COLOR_WARNING="\e[1;33m"
# Definitions
KEY_DIR="/etc/apt/keyrings"
PPA_DIR="/etc/apt/sources.list.d"
KEY_HOST="keyserver.ubuntu.com"
PPA_HOST="launchpadcontent.net"
```

`add-launchpad-ppa.sh` file content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script:  add-launchpad-ppa.sh
# Author: Lorenz Keel (AskUbuntu)
# Purpose: Add PGP key in apt keyring
# Usage:   sudo bash <script_dir>/add-launchpad-ppa.sh ppa:[ppa_user]/[ppa_name]
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Error status variables
STATUS_OK=0
STATUS_ERROR=1

# Execute it as root user
if [ "${USER}" != root ]; then
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}ERROR: must be root! Exiting...${COLOR_OFF}"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Check dependencies
if [ -z "$(command -v curl)" ]; then
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}ERROR: unmet dependencies. Run the command:${COLOR_OFF}"
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}sudo apt install curl${COLOR_OFF}"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Load configuration file
SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" &>/dev/null && pwd)"
SCRIPT_FILE="$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")"
CONF_FILE="${SCRIPT_DIR}/${SCRIPT_FILE/.sh/.conf}"
if [ -f "${CONF_FILE}" ]; then
  # shellcheck source=/dev/null
  source "${CONF_FILE}"
else
  echo "ERROR: missing ${CONF_FILE} file! Exiting..."
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Comment code blocks
if [ -n "${BASH}" ]; then
  shopt -s expand_aliases
  alias BEGINCOMMENT="if [ ]; then"
  alias ENDCOMMENT="fi"
fi

# Check input parameters
PPA_PREFIX="$(echo "$1" | cut -d ":" -f 1)"
PPA_USER="$(echo "$1" | cut -d "/" -f 1 | cut -d ":" -f 2)"
PPA_NAME="$(echo "$1" | cut -d "/" -f 2)"
if [ "${PPA_PREFIX}" != "ppa" ] || [ -z "${PPA_USER}" ] || [ -z "${PPA_NAME}" ]; then
  echo "Usage: sudo bash ${SCRIPT_FILE} ppa:[ppa_user]/[ppa_name]"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Create list file
echo -n "→ Creating ${PPA_USER}.list in ${PPA_DIR}... "
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=${KEY_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg] https://ppa.${PPA_HOST}/${PPA_USER}/${PPA_NAME}/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" \
  | tee "${PPA_DIR}/${PPA_USER}".list &> /dev/null
if [ -s "${PPA_DIR}/${PPA_USER}".list ]; then
  echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"
else
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}ERROR: file creation fail${COLOR_OFF}"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Get fingerprint and download the key
echo -n "→ Retrieving fingerprint from https://${PPA_HOST}/~${PPA_USER}/+archive/ubuntu/${PPA_NAME}... "
PPA_FINGER="$(curl -sL "https://launchpad.net/~${PPA_USER}/+archive/ubuntu/${PPA_NAME}" | sed -n -e 's/^.*key_fingerprint//p' | cut -d \" -f 3)"
SCRIPT_NAME="${SCRIPT_FILE%.*}"
USER_NAME="${SUDO_USER:-${USER}}"
TMP_DIR="$(sudo -u "${USER_NAME}" mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}${SCRIPT_NAME}.XXXX")"
TMP_FILE="tmp-${PPA_USER}"
if curl -sfL "https://${KEY_HOST}/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x${PPA_FINGER}" -o "${TMP_DIR}/${TMP_FILE}"; then
  echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"
else
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}ERROR: download fail${COLOR_OFF}"
  rm -rf "${TMP_DIR}"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Convert the keyfile
echo -n "→ Converting keyfile... "
# Remove first character (is a blank)
KEY_TYPE="$(file "${TMP_DIR}/${TMP_FILE}" | awk -F ':' '{print substr($2, 2, length($2)-1)}')"
if [ "${KEY_TYPE}" = 'PGP public key block Public-Key (old)' ]; then
  gpg --batch --yes --dearmor --keyring=gnupg-ring "${TMP_DIR}/${TMP_FILE}"
  mv "${TMP_DIR}/${TMP_FILE}.gpg" "${TMP_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg"
  echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"
elif [ "${KEY_TYPE}" = 'PGP public key block Secret-Key' ]; then
  gpg --batch --yes --no-default-keyring --keyring=gnupg-ring:"${TMP_DIR}/temp-keyring.gpg" --quiet --import "${TMP_DIR}/${TMP_FILE}"
  gpg --batch --yes --no-default-keyring --keyring=gnupg-ring:"${TMP_DIR}/temp-keyring.gpg" --export --output "${TMP_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg"
  echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"
elif [ "${KEY_TYPE}" = 'PGP/GPG key public ring (v4)' ]; then
  mv "${TMP_DIR}/${TMP_FILE}" "${TMP_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg"
  echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"
else
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}ERROR: invalid input keyfile format${COLOR_OFF}"
  rm -rf "${TMP_DIR}"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Move keyfile
echo -n "→ Moving keyfile to ${KEY_DIR}... "
# Check if keyfile exist
if [ -f "${TMP_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg" ]; then
  mkdir -p  "${KEY_DIR}"
  mv "${TMP_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg" "${KEY_DIR}/${PPA_USER}-keyring.gpg"
  echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"
else
  echo -e "${COLOR_ERROR}ERROR: keyfile does not exist${COLOR_OFF}"
  rm -rf "${TMP_DIR}"
  exit "${STATUS_ERROR}"
fi

# Cleanup
echo -n "→ Cleaning temporary files... "
rm -rf "${TMP_DIR}"
echo -e "${COLOR_OK}Done${COLOR_OFF}"

# Exit
exit "${STATUS_OK}"
```

The script performs the following operations:

1. Check if the script is called with `sudo`
2. Check if `curl` is installed
3. Source the `add-launchpad-ppa.conf` that must be put in the same folder of `add-launchpad-ppa.sh` file
4. Get the input to build some internal variables. Just for an example, the input for adding the musicbrainz picard app ([https://launchpad.net/~musicbrainz-developers/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Emusicbrainz-developers/+archive/ubuntu/stable)) is `ppa:musicbrainz-developers/stable` (as stated in the paragraph "Adding this PPA to your system"), so that the command to add this ppa is `sudo bash ~/.local/bin/add-launchpad-ppa.sh ppa:musicbrainz-developers/stable` (considering that the script is located in `~/.local/bin/`).
5. From the above data, create the `.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. In the example, the file will be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/musicbrainz-developers.list`
6. Parse the html page of the ppa and download (in a temporary folder) the ppa keyring.
7. Convert the key in the proper format, using `gpg` commands. These convertion commands (in the `if-elif-else` statements) have been copied/modified from several answers in AskUbuntu about the topics related to `apt-key` deprecation.
8. Move the key in the folder configured in `.conf` file. In the example, the key will be `/etc/apt/keyrings/musicbrainz-developers-keyring.gpg`
9. Final cleanup of temporary files.

In other words, it is a simple replacement of native command `add-apt-repository`. **There is margin for a lot of improvements of this script**, I'm aware of it, but for my personal usage I find it very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to save some of your time.

For my personal needs I have created special [Python script](https://github.com/N0rbert/srslsud) named `srslsud` (Save/Restore Software List Script for Ubuntu and Debian).
It will save all APT repositories, their GPG keys; lists of Snaps, Flatpaks and Ubuntu Make apps to JSON files from the first machine.
Then you can restore this list using same JSON files on the second machine.

For you case you can use its functionality partially on old machine:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-gi python3-apt software-properties-common python3-jsonpickle

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N0rbert/srslsud/master/srslsud.py
chmod +x srslsud.py
./srslsud.py apt_save
./srslsud.py apt_load

cat apt.sh | grep apt-key
```

and then parse above output to get actual keys.

But for the best productivity I would recommend to run `sudo bash ./apt.sh` on fresh machine with the same Ubuntu version and give it a chance to do all the job.
This method is still applicable even for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so `apt-key` deprecation is not a problem.